# Really umount external drive

Tags: linux, debian, mount, partition, disk

I had a USB drive mounted on `/dev/sdb1` and I want to reformat from NTFS to ext3. I did `umount -l` which unmounted the disk. I deleted the old partition using `cfdisk`. I ran `mkfs.ext3`, but got the error:

> /dev/sdb1 is apparently in use...

After googling I tried to `cat /proc/mounts` and found it there:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/moviesold
```

How do I remove the reference from there? How did it get there? More specifically what can I run to "really umount"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `umount`. You ran `umount -l`, which specifically tells `umount` to leave the filesystem mounted until all processes are done with it. You really shouldn't need `umount -l` most of the time; the only purpose it serves is freeing up the mount point so you can mount something new there while the currently mounted partition is still in use. Now that you've already lazy unmounted it, if you figure out which process still has a file open on the filesystem and close it it will unmount automatically

Comment: Thanks, I thought the -l meant "force unmount" for some reason. I still cant format but that is a separate question.